# identifier not found, even with argument-dependent lookup and operator << is ambiguous

Tags: c++

In my C++ function, I am trying to do this `cout <<getVoxelWidth();` but these are the 2 errors I am getting

`error C2593: 'operator <<' is ambiguous`
and
`error C3861: 'getVoxelWidth': identifier not found, even with argument-dependent lookup`

I have included the .h file that `getVoxelWidth` is located and here is how it is defined.

`const double getVoxelWidth() const  { return getVoxelDim("voxel_size_x"); }`

Comment: `getVoxelWidth` is a member function. Are you calling it from another member of the same class? If not, you'll need an object of that class to call it on.

Comment: Is `getVoxelWidth` contained in a namespace?

Comment: @fiscblog: I doubt it; only a member function can have a `const` specifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your signature implies a class function and you call it as it was a free function.

Probably you meant `obj.getVoxelWidth()`. After that the other error probably goes away or changes.

Comment: got it to compile. I had to use `obj->getVoxelWidth()`. When I used `obj.getVoxelWidth()` I got `error C2228: left of '.getVoxelWidth' must have class/struct/union type
        type is 'obj *'
        did you intend to use '->' instead?`

Comment: the proper form depends whether obj is pointer or the object itself